# PDO Execute() function not binding the parameter

Tags: php, pdo

I have the following function. I expect it to print the number of rows in the table provided in its argument.

```
private function getTotalCount($tbl){
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM :tbl ;";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute(array(
        ':tbl' => $tbl
    ));
    $data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($data);
}
```

But the function is not printing anything...

When I replace the function to something like this:

```
private function getTotalCount($tbl){
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM $tbl ;";
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
    $data = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    print_r($data);
}
```

Then it works fine and print the number of rows.

**QUESTION:** Why the execute() function not binding the :tbl parameter to $tbl ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sadly MySQL PDO doesn't accept parameters for SQL keywords, table names, view names and field names. This doesn't really come up in the [main manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php), but is mentioned a couple of times in [comments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php#71127).

The solution you have in the second piece of code is the workaround, although you may wish to sanitise the table name first (checking against a white list of table names would be ideal). More info: [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-name-as-parameter)